# Zend\Mail\Message::addTo expects a string, AddressInterface, array, AddressList, or Traversable as its first argument; received "NULL"

Tags: magento2

when I create cron job and run it 
It shows me error at cron task whick

> Zend\Mail\Message::addTo expects a string, AddressInterface, array,
>   AddressList, or Traversable as its first argument; received "NULL"

kindly help me if any know about this .

Comment: the error message is quite clear.

Comment: but @PhilippSander i don't know how to solved this .can you please explain this ?

Comment: provide relevant code

Comment: i solved this . in newsletter subscribers one email attribute send null in queue.so that's why this error show.

Answer (score 0):

The function receives NULL when it expects a string email address.

I saw this when the admin email for a transactional was empty but the flag (Yes/No admin configuration) to activate the transactional email to admin was set to 'YES'.
If you have such flag (Yes/No admin configuration) than set it to No. Otherwise code it yourself.

If this error comes from a transactional email sent to customers than you have some sort of bug in Magento code or in your modules/extensions installed.